# Memory leak when inflating from XML and using setActionView on an ActionBar's MenuItem

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-actionbar

In this is a very simple `Activity` with an `ActionBar` containing a single `MenuItem` "search". I want to set an ActionView to the search button and I use the `MenuItem.setActionView(int ResId)` to pass the XML layout.  inflate a layout that I want to attach to a `MenuItem` as an Action view.

The `button` simply starts the exact same `Activity`. "Don't keep activities" is set in the dev options.

Problem: after a OnClickListener have been set on a widget within the action view, `MainActivity` is never garbage collected (see MAT below). However if I create a view hierarchy in java (instead of inflating it) it is GC's as it should be.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Click");

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    setContentView(button);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem searchIcon = menu.add("search");
    searchIcon.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    // I set the ActionView here:
    searchIcon.setActionView(R.layout.action_search_form);
    ViewGroup vg = ((ViewGroup)searchIcon.getActionView());
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)vg.findViewById(R.id.search_clear_btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    return true;
}
}
```

The number of objects corresponds exactly to the # of times I clicked on the `button`.
if I remove the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` block, the # of objects is not exactly 1 but always below 10.

[image]

Comment: One is from your `OrientationManager`, which has an open sensor listener. I don't know if your MAT data is from where an activity was in the foreground or not; if not, make sure that `OrientationManager` unregisters from sensors. For the rest, it feels like something in your activity is interfering with the normal cleanup process when the activity is no longer in the foreground, but that is just an educated guess. I see nothing that would tie into your "purely from Java code" statement.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have reproduced the issue on a blank new Android project with a single Activity. I replaced the code in the question.  At this point I am wondering if the issue could be related to the ActionBar itself. What do you think?

Comment: In the absence of flags to the contrary, `startActivity()` will create a new activity instance. So, if on instance 1, you click the button to create instance 2, where you click the button to create instance 3, there will be three instances. Only if you are pressing BACK in between button clicks will activities be finished and therefore eligible for GC.

Comment: @CommonsWare: As soon as I add the listener to the button the # of instances (and the heap) never stops increasing. If I leave the app and come back I still have the same # of instances (up to hundreds). However if I remove the listener the system kills instance, frees memory and if I leave and come back I have only one remaining instance.

Comment: Please define "leave [the app] and come back". If you mean that you pressed HOME or something, when you "come back" you will either have exactly the same number of instances as before (because your process was not terminated) or zero/one instance (because your process was terminated). The listener has no effect on this.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Ok forget the leave the app thing. With the listener, I can have up to hundreds (1 per StartActivity()) of instances of MainActivity and the heap is continuously growing. Without, I have up to 30 instances (it grows and declines) of MainActivity for hundreds of StartActivity() and the heap is stable. Anyway, thank you for taking the time to look into the issue. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @NathanZ did you find an answer ?

Comment: @NirHartmann In this project I ended up creating the view entirely programmatically (no xml inflation) and the leaks were gone.